# How to call Async Web service in Java

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous

I thought there would be lot more info/tutorials on this one, but some how I'm not able to figure out how to call an async SOAP web service using Java. The web service in question may not necessarily be a Java web service. I only have access to web service's run time WSDL.
Any pointers will be greatly helpful.

Also would it be possible to dynamically call such a web service? The Dynamic Invocation Interface method `javax.xml.rpc.Call` allows that for sync calls, but haven't found anything on async calls.

Comment: what kind of web service? REST? SOAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the JAX-WS standard for the use of Future objects to communicate, asynchronously, with services. For some examples see [CXF documentation on JAX-WS clients](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/developing-a-consumer.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do an asynchronous web service invocation, so that the client is not blocked waiting for the response. Check this [link text](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e15184/asynch.htm)